# Comparação de string dando errado - Python

Tags: python, string, comparação

Eu tenho essa função que verifica se o código que eu digitei está na lista de códigos, mas por mais que o código esteja na lista ele não entra no if e retorna false. Não consigo entender porque não funciona.

Segue o código:

```
def procurando(escolha, codigos, produtos, precos):
    print(codigos)
    verdade = False
    if escolha == 1:
            codigo = int(input("Código do produto: "))
            for i in codigos:
                    print("entrou no for")
                    print(codigo)
                    print(i)
                    if codigo == i:
                            print("entrou no if?")
                            verdade = True
                            print("Produto: {}                        Preço: {}".format(produtos[i], precos[i]))
                            break;

    elif escolha == 2:
            nome = input("Nome do produto: ")
            for i, v in enumerate(produtos):
                    print(produtos[i])
                    if v == nome:
                            print("Foi encontrado 1 resultado.")
                            print("Produto: {}                        Preço: {}".format(produtos[i], precos[i]))
                            verdade = True
                            break;
    print(verdade)
    return verdade
```

Comment: E como você executou a função? Consegue gerar um [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código está correto, a única coisa que está errada é o for para buscar pelo código.
O correto seria fazer da mesma forma como fez para buscar pelo nome do produto.

Lembrando que como está convertendo a entrada do código para um número `codigo = int(input("Código do produto: "))`, se os valores da lista de códigos forem strings, ex `codigos = ["10", "20", "30"]`, a comparação sempre será false.

```
10 == 10 > True
"10" == 10 > False      #tipos diferentes
"10" == "10" > True
```

```
def procurando(escolha, codigos, produtos, precos):
    print(codigos)
    verdade = False
    if escolha == 1:
            codigo = int(input("Código do produto: "))
            for i, v in enumerate(codigos):
                    print("entrou no for")
                    print(codigo)
                    print(v)
                    if codigo == v:
                            print("entrou no if?")
                            verdade = True
                            print("Produto: {}                        Preço: {}".format(produtos[i], precos[i]))
                            break;

    elif escolha == 2:
            nome = input("Nome do produto: ")
            for i, v in enumerate(produtos):
                    print(produtos[i])
                    if v == nome:
                            print("Foi encontrado 1 resultado.")
                            print("Produto: {}                        Preço: {}".format(produtos[i], precos[i]))
                            verdade = True
                            break;
    print(verdade)
    return verdade
```

Comment: eu atualizei o código pra ficar desse jeito ai, porém ele continua não entrando no if.. a lista de códigos vem de um arquivo txt, o \n pode atrapalhar na comparação?

Comment: É possível, depende de como você está fazendo a leitura do arquivo.

Comment: Aaaah, eu converti o valor de "v" para int, ai funcionou